# tell javac to create all valid classes

Tags: java, javac

How can i tell javac(jdk-1.6) to create all valid classes? For example:

```
javac a.java b.java
```

And for example b.java contains errors. I want to get a.class, but javac create nothing cause of syntax errors in b.java

thanks

**upd**: as i see, eclipse java compiler solves that problem

Answer (score 0):

This probably depends on the compiler. Maybe what you are looking for, is an incremental compiler. The compiler bundled with Eclipse IDE is an incremental compiler, but what interests me is, why would you want to build your code in this way at all?

**Edit**

I got the wrong idea earlier. I see you want to do this through code. You can use this implementation:

http://www.accordess.com/wpblog/an-overview-of-java-compilation-api-jsr-199/

It lets you control the compilation units you want to pass.

Comment: i need to use javax.tools.JavaCompiler to generate java classes. But sources that i have, contains some old files that may contains errors

Comment: @user1312837: Why not just fix them? I find it very rare to really want to be able to run a half-valid codebase.

Comment: @JonSkeet sources generate by different software, that i can't fix

Comment: @user1312837: So if you can't fix them, they're never going to be valid - so don't include them in the list of files to compile...

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry but how can i do it in runtime?

Comment: Yea. If you have no control over those files (generated sources as you said), and they are part of the application, your application wont work unless you get them sorted. In this case, you can change the application that is generating those sources or ignore them during compilation like @JonSkeet said.

Comment: Are you using a build tool like Maven or Ant?

Comment: You can specify directories and wildcards like javac <directory>\\*_generated.java, if you are using javac. If you are using ant or maven, excluding files from compilation is easier.

Comment: @r3st0r3 thanks for the article link. But i cant find, how can i skip non-valid files from compilation? As far as I dont know their names in advance